# How to select an option from the dropdown when the dropdown has same ID

Tags: ruby, capybara

I'm trying to select a value from a drop-down.

This is the HTML:

```
<select id="selectFilter">
  <option value></option>
  <option value="FEE">FEE</option>
  <option value="PW">PW</option>
```

My code to select is:

```
select('PW', :from => 'selectFilter')
```

I get an error since the id `selectFilter` is the same at two places

```
Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching "selectFilter" (Capybara::Ambiguous)
```

How do I select the options I need?

Comment: By definition a HTML document can't have multiple identical ID. Are you responsible for the HTML generation, or is it in the wild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really do have two elements with the same id then you really should fix your HTML.  If on the other hand you have one select with that id and another select with that as the name, placeholder, or label text you can do

```
find('#selectFilter').find(:option, 'PW').select_option
```

which would find specifically by id and may solve your issue.

If you do actually have two elements with the id and refuse to/can't  fix your HTML then you can scope the initial find to one part of the page somehow like

```
find('#some_section').select('PW', from: 'selectFilter')
```

or if there is only one 'PW' option on the page you could just do

```
find(:option, 'PW').select_option
```

Comment: @ Tom Walpole. I could not use either of the options because both the drop downs had same ID and both had "PW" options. I tried to use your second option but i got an error like "unable to find the CSS ('#ome_Section'). So finally i just tried "page.first(:option, 'PW').select_option" and it worked by selecting the first PW option in the   first drop down i believe .

Comment: @RPD  the #some_section was just an example CSS selector that would select a section of the page that only has the one select you want, but not the other - you would have to customize that based on your page structure/elements.  First will work, but you may want to add a minimum: 1 option to it `page.first(:option, 'PW', minimum: 1).select_option`  to make sure it will wait a little time if the option isn't yet on the page or the visit hasn't yet finished loading.  Without one of the count type options first won't wait by default.

Comment: I have added  minimum: 1 option and it is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

HTML `id` attributes are supposed to be unique on the page. You need to rename at least one of your `selectFilter`s so they don't collide.

If for some reason you really can't/won't pick unique `id`s, Capybara's [`select`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FActions%3Aselect) will also find `name`s and `label`s, but you have to provide something unique for it to find the right element.